# PHP Check if 10 minutes has gone by

Tags: php, mysql

I want to compare two `dates` with each other to see if 10 minutes has passed.

This is the code that I've got but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

I get the first date from my table (which is saved as a `timestamp`, example: 2017-03-26 22:33:45) and then I want to compare it with the `time` that is right `now`.

```
$sql = "SELECT saved_time from table1 where email = '$email'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $savedTime = $row[0];
}
$now = time();
if (/*10 minutes has passed between saved time and now*/) {
    echo "Your account is unlocked";
} else if (/*10 minutes hasn't passed*/) {
    echo "Your account is locked";
}
```

Comment: check if ($now < $savedTime)

Comment: btw; you're using prepare/execute. Why not use a "real" prepared statement? what you have now still leaves you open to an sql injection.

Comment: `select * from table T where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,.saved_time,NOW()) > 10` if the mysql solution is okay for you.

Comment: @Xorifelse Yeah, I'm the type that used to have Rice Krispies *with* my sugar. I did say *"used to"*  ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know that I'm not going the correct way with the SQL statement, I will fix that later on, just want to make this work first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This code:

```
    $timezone = "Asia/Kolkata";// Select Timezone as of your Preference or MySQL Server Timezone
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    $sql = "SELECT saved_time from table1 where email = :email";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $savedTime = $row[0];
    }

    // Uncomment below Line if $savedTime is in MySQL DATETIME Format
    // $savedTime = strtotime($savedTime);
    $now = time();

    if (round(($now - $savedTime) / 60,2) >= 10){
       echo "Your account is unlocked";
    } elseif (round(($now - $savedTime) / 60,2) < 10){
       echo "Your account is locked";
    }
```

Comment: *"`where email = '$email'`"* - screams sql injection btw.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Thanks for suggetion... updated above code for avoiding SQL Injection.

Comment: Looking at the code I'm presuming it will work, +1 for adding the security.

Comment: @SachinPATIL tried to use this code and it seems to work but the time is wrong. I echoed the "round(($now - $savedTime) / 60,2)" and it gives me -120. As in that I have to wait for 120 minutes before it reaches 0.

Comment: what is `$savedTime` value and `$now` value, you are checking with?

Comment: @SachinPATIL     $savedTime = 1490569812. $now = 1490562981.

Comment: It clearly shows that, `$savedTime` has higher value already. Check the updated code above, and do the amendments

Answer (score 0):

```
if $now = time(); #(this will generate a timestamp)
```

assuming `$savedTime = $row[0];` is a MySQL date field, you can do

```
$savedTimeTimestamp= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $savedTime);
```

...now 10 time 60 seconds is 10 minutes, so

```
if ($now > ($savedTimeTimestamp+600))
```

should do the job

Answer (score 0):

If mysql solution is fine for you, then

```
select * from table T where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,.saved_time,NOW()) > 10
```

If you need it in php, then

```
$db_time = $row['saved_time'];//as you have stored in timestamp already
$curr_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$diff =  round(abs($db_time - $curr_time) / 60,2);
if($diff > 10)
```

**Update**

```
select now() as curr_time, saved_time from table where COND;
```

then in php

```
$diff = $curr_time-$saved_time;
if($diff > (10*60 ))
```

I am not sure whether this will work. But just an idea.

Comment: $diff becomes 120 minutes

Comment: Might be some timezone difference between mysql timestamp and php selected timezone. Try print `echo date('Y-m-d',$db_time);`. And you can find the difference. If so better using mysql.

Comment: For some reason I get 1970-01-01 when I do that

Comment: Make sure you passed the correct timestamp value in date() function. You might be having wrong value in $db_time. Just a guess :)